# How to open outlook mail from java with prepoulaed body with html code

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

Can any one help me with a java code where i want that my html code to be added in body of the mail and the mail client should pop up so that a person can enter the To: and can edit the body if needed.
    I have tried this code but this one just sends the mail.What i want is the my mail client should popup with body already entered.

```
package you;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;


public class test1 {
    public void fnSendMail(String Status) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, URISyntaxException {
    String htmlContent = null;
    if (Status.equals("Completed")) {


        htmlContent = "<html><br>Below is Test Execution Report.<br>Please find the attached for Detailed Results"
                + "<br><br><table border='1' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='3' width='40%' bordercolor='#999999' style='border-collapse: collapse;'>"
                + "<tr><th>SNo</th><th>Run_Method</th><th>abc_name</th><th>Execution_Status</th></tr>" +  "</table>"
                + "<br><br><br><h3 style='color:FireBrick;'>Please do not respond to this mail </h3></html>";
    } else {
        htmlContent = "<html><br>" + "<h3 style='color:FireBrick;'>Automation got failed due to some issue, hence "
                + "Please verify Maven Errors.<br><br>Execution Status till failure is attached.</h3></html>";
    }
    String from = "abc@cdf.com";
    String host = "x.y.z";
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        BodyPart messageBodyText = new MimeBodyPart();
        message.setSubject("CSI API Automated Testing Report is " + Status);
        messageBodyText.setContent(htmlContent, "text/html");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyText);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          test1 test2= new test1();
            try {
                test2.fnSendMail("Completed");
                System.out.println("Email sent.");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Failed to sent email.");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Any other way to do this will also work, but i need is java and javascript only

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling Transport.send you have to call [MimeMessage.saveChanges](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#saveChanges()) then use [MimeMessage.writeTo](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#writeTo(java.io.OutputStream)) to save it to the filesystem as '.eml'.  Then open that file with [java.awt.Desktop.open](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-) to launch the email client. Your system must have a mime association with eml or the open call will fail.

If the O/S mime type for `eml` is not set to something like `outlook.exe /eml %1` then you might have to resort to using the process API to launch outlook directly using the `eml` switch.  For example, if you want to preview the `foo.eml` draft message then the command would be:

`outlook.exe /eml foo.eml`

You'll have to handle clean up after the email client is closed.

You also have to think about the security implications of email messages being left on the file system.

Comment: i tried this approach also but while executing Desktop.open it was giving me operation failed.